# Find a set of vectors $\{u,v\}$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$ that spans the solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Question: Find a set of vectors $\{u,v\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that spans the solution set of the equations:

$$\begin{align}x - y - z + w = 0 \\
x + 2y - z + 3w = 0\end{align}$$

Reducing these I get:

$$\begin{align}x &= z -\frac{5}{2}w \\
y &= -\frac{2}{3}w \\
z &= u \\
w &= v\end{align}$$

In other words:

$$(x,y,z,w) = u(1,0,1,0) + v(-\frac{5}{2}, -\frac{2}{3}, 0, 1)$$

But this is wrong for some reason and I'm not understanding where I went wrong here. Any input?

Comment: yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Please consider modifying the title, that does not reflect the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your original equations (assuming the $3x$ is supposed to be $3w$), you can conclude by subtracting one of them from the other that $$y=-\frac23w,$$ from which you can conclude by substitution that $$x=z-\frac53w.$$ That's where you made your mistake.

Incidentally, if you instead write $w=3v,$ then you can instead have $$(x,y,z,w)=u(1,0,1,0)+v(-5,-2,0,3),$$ which looks nicer.

It's worth noting, though, that you are looking for **vectors** $u,v$ to span your subspace. You should *not* set the *constants* $z,w$ equal to these vectors. I recommend instead that you write $z=\alpha,w=3\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are arbitrary constants. Then you can conclude that $$(x,y,z,w)=\alpha(1,0,1,0)+\beta(-5,-2,0,3),$$ and setting $u=(1,0,1,0)$ and $v=(-5,-2,0,3)$, we have $\{u,v\}$ as the desired spanning set.

Comment: WOW, what a silly mistake that was! Thanks!

Comment: Quite all right. Check my edit, though for another issue that you should address.

Comment: Yea I noticed, I'll be keeping that in mind because it can cause confusion.